# Is $scope of one state lost in another state in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

While having multiple routed states in angularjs, each of the states are manipulated by separate controllers (in my case), for now i am using view model by **this** operator. Now i need to know if i have a property in a $scope variable which matches with the property of other state what happens to the scope of other state ?

Comment: Yes, when a view is destroyed and replaced with another, the old controller and its scope are destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

When instantiated controller creates a brand new scope object prototypically linked with parent $scope object. So if you have 2 separate sibling controllers their respective `$scope` objects are totally separate and have no connection.

The `this` when using controller with `controllerAs` syntax will attach properties onto `$scope` under the controllerAs specified key (if you specified `vm` in `"ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm"` then your `this.someProp` in controller will be pointing to the `$scope.vm.someProp`).

Thus technically it makes no difference whether you use `this` or `$scope` regarding your particular question.

If you want to have a shared state between the controllers the best approach is to have a service that will expose it, and you will get the state from both controllers injecting that service.